# Python tree traversal from specific breadth

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I've been trying to solve this probably very simple problem for a day now, and I still can't get my head around the problem.

Suppose we have a dictionary, e.g.

```
di = {'a' : ['b','c','d'],c : ['g','j','k'],k : ['z','y']}
```

I've been trying to write out only elements, which appear lower in the tree than an element specified. So for e.g if I call get_low('a',2), it will return the elements [g,j,k,z,y], so all elements down the a tree from the second level down.

My attempt:

```
def get_low(obj, level, children = [], generation = 0):

    if level == 0:
        children = [obj]

    generation += 1
    #print (generation, level)
    for child in di[obj]:
        if level <= generation:
            children.append(child)
            get_low(child, level,children, generation)

    return set(children)
```

This although prints some of the correct values, two things don't work: 1.) it doesn't include obj if level is set at zero and 2.) if I set level to e.g. 4, it doesn't throw empty set() as a result.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it a bit different but I think it gets the right nodes:

```
di = {'a' : ['b','c','d'], 'c' : ['g','j','k'], 'k' : ['z','y']}

children = set()

def get_low(obj, level):
    if level==0:
        children.add(obj)
    level -= 1
    if di.get(obj):
        for i in di.get(obj):
            if level<=0:
                children.add(i)
            get_low(i,level)    
    else:
        return  

get_low('a', 2)
print children
```

For example for `level=2` the result is:

```
set(['y', 'k', 'j', 'z', 'g'])
```

for `level=0` is:

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'k', 'j', 'y', 'z'])
```

and for `level=4`:

```
set([])
```